# Keyboard backlight UI stuck on Touch Bar MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

Whenever I try to increase or decrease the brightness of the keyboard backlight — using the Touch Bar on my MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina) — the GUI just shows this:

[image: Keyboard backlight UI frozen in macOS]

What does this mean? Is some hardware broken, or just a software bug?

Comment: Most likely a software bug. Did you try restarting your MacBook? What's the version of macOS running on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, and it's the latest Catalina

Comment: Do you have an external keyboard connected? If yes, try reconnecting/replugging it in.

Comment: You can also use a Terminal command to refresh the Touch Bar. Launch Terminal and type in the command pkill "Touch Bar agent" and hit Return. Hope it will help.

Comment: Great and posted as an answer:)

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with the OP; but unfortunately this trick did not work for me on the latest version of Catalina - `10.15.4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a Terminal command to refresh the Touch Bar.

1. Launch Terminal
2. Type in the command `pkill "Touch Bar agent"` and hit Return.

It should help you to fix this issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with the OP; but unfortunately this trick did not work for me on the latest version of Catalina - `10.15.4`.